# Extract specific substring using javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have the following string:

```
mickey mouse WITH friend:goofy WITH pet:pluto
```

What is the best way in javascript to take that string and extract out all the "key:value" pairs into some object variable? The colon is the separator. Though I may or may not be able to guarantee the WITH will be there.

Comment: I think the string lacks some consistency. Are you certain the the first word before : is always the key. And the first word after the : is always the value?

Comment: You can use regex, or just [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on whitespaces and the colon into substrings. What have you tried?

Comment: @Xeano Certain for both.

Comment: Check my answer, it gives you Object {mickey: "goofy", goofy: "pluto"}  - I believe this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array = str.match(/\w+\:\w+/g);
```

Then split each item in array using `":"`, to get the key value pairs.

Here is the code:

```
function getObject(str) {
  var ar = str.match(/\w+\:\w+/g);
  var outObj = {};
  for (var i=0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    var item = ar[i];
    var s = item.split(":");
    outObj[s[0]] = s[1];
  }
  return outObj;  
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check for `ar === null`

Answer (score 1):

```
myString.split(/\s+/).reduce(function(map, str) {
    var parts = str.split(":");
    if (parts.length > 1)
        map[parts.shift()] = parts.join(":");
    return map;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
"mickey WITH friend:goofy WITH pet:pluto".split(":")
```

it will return the array, then Looping over the array.

Answer (score 0):

The string pattern has to be consistent in one or the other way atleast.
Use split function of javascript and split by the word that occurs in common(our say space Atleast)
Then you need to split each of those by using : as key, and get the required values into an object. 
Hope that's what you were long for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way for example:

```
    var myString = "mickey WITH friend:goofy WITH pet:pluto";

    function someName(str, separator) {
        var arr = str.split(" "),
            arr2 = [],
            obj = {};
        for(var i = 0, ilen = arr.length; i < ilen; i++) {
            if ( arr[i].indexOf(separator) !== -1 ) {
              arr2 = arr[i].split(separator);
              obj[arr2[0]] = arr2[1];
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

    var x = someName(myString, ":");

    console.log(x);
```

Comment: `match` takes a regex. Use `indexOf` or omit that line, you still can check on `arr2.length`